# Issue with conforming to Objective-C protocol from Swift NSObject subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

This piece of code works absolutely fine in Swift 1.1

```
// Obj-C

@import Foundation;

@protocol HashableObject <NSObject>
- (NSUInteger)hash;
@end

// Swift

import Foundation

@objc class Object: NSObject, HashableObject {

    func hash() -> UInt {
        return 0
    }
}
```

However, in latest Swift 1.2 and XCode 6.3beta2 the compiler complains that `Method 'hash()' overrides Objective-C method 'hash' from superclass 'NSObject'`

Is that a bug, or something else has fundamentally changed and the code is wrong? Are there any workarounds to this? I have numerous things in my code that need to conform to certain protocols from Objective-C libraries and this essentially breaks everything with no apparent solution other than wait for the next Swift release.

Comment: What's the question, do you want to override the standard method `hash` or create your own ?

Comment: I am trying to conform to an Objective-C library's protocol. One of its required methods is `- (NSUInteger)hash;` I only mocked the above just to convey the essence of my problem.

Comment: The thing is, `NSObject` already conforms your protocol and if you want the `Object` to implement its own `hash` you'll have to override the method. Is there any issue at doing so ?

Comment: Yes there is, if in the example above I include the `override` keyword, it will complain that `Method does not override any method from its superclass` which makes sense because `hash` in `NSObject` is a computed property. If instead I try to make an overriding computed property, the the compiler complains that I don't conform to `HashableObject` protocol.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta 2) you can override the `hash` property
of `NSObject` as a computed property:

```
class Object: NSObject {
    override var hash: Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but for some reason it won't accept conformance to the other (Obj-C) protocol I want to conform which has a required method declared as `-(NSUInteger)hash`

Comment: @Thanos: NSObject already has a "hash" property. You cannot have a property and a function with the same name.

Comment: I understand that. Unfortunately, this is a weakness of the 3rd party lib and waiting for a fix from their end. Too bad it suddenly broke in latest XCode/Swift.

Comment: I love this guys which are life savers!

Answer (score 2):

`NSObject` already has [`hash` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash):

```
protocol NSObjectProtocol {
    var hash: Int { get }
```

And, Swift 1.2 detects these erroneous overrides. From the release notes:

> Swift now detects discrepancies between overloading and overriding in the Swift type system and the effective behavior seen via the Objective-C runtime. (18391046, 18383574)
>
> For example, the following conflict between the Objective-C setter for “property” in a class and the method “setProperty” in its extension is now diagnosed:
>
> ```
> class A : NSObject {
>   var property: String = "Hello" // note: Objective-C method 'setProperty:’
>                                  // previously declared by setter for
>                                  // 'property’ here
> }
> extension A {
>     func setProperty(str: String) { } // error: method ‘setProperty’
>                                       // redeclares Objective-C method
>                                       //'setProperty:’
> }
> ```

Comment: I read this. If I try to override hash as a computer property, the compiler complains that I don't conform to the protocol because I don't have `- (NSUInteger)hash` implemented. How can I work around this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know. If you can, do not use the name `hash` in the protocol.