# Swift - Type '*' does not conform to protocol '*'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I got this error message when trying to create a `Message` class.

```
'Message' does not conform to protocol 'JSQMessageData'
```

`JSQMessageData` got from https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

[image]

My code

```
import Foundation

class Message : NSObject, JSQMessageData {

    var senderId_ : String!
    var senderDisplayName_ : String!
    var date_ : NSDate
    var isMediaMessage_ : Bool
    var hash_ : Int = 0
    var text_ : String

    init(senderId: String, senderDisplayName: String?, isMediaMessage: Bool, hash: Int, text: String) {
        self.senderId_ = senderId
        self.senderDisplayName_ = senderDisplayName
        self.date_ = NSDate()
        self.isMediaMessage_ = isMediaMessage
        self.hash_ = hash
        self.text_ = text
    }

    func senderId() -> String! {
        return senderId_;
    }

    func senderDisplayName() -> String! {
        return senderDisplayName_;
    }

    func date() -> NSDate! {
        return date_;
    }

    func isMediaMessage() -> Bool! {
        return isMediaMessage_;
    }

    func hash() -> Int? {
        return hash_;
    }

    func text() -> String! {
        return text_;
    }
}
```

JSQMessageData.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JSQMessageMediaData.h"

@protocol JSQMessageData <NSObject>

@required

- (NSString *)senderId;
- (NSString *)senderDisplayName;
- (NSDate *)date;
- (BOOL)isMediaMessage;
- (NSUInteger)hash;

@optional

- (NSString *)text;
- (id<JSQMessageMediaData>)media;

@end
```

How to fix this protocol issue?

Comment: The full compiler output (in the "Report navigator") should have more information about the problem.

Comment: It's just showing this error message sir.

Comment: possible related: [Issue with conforming to Objective-C protocol from Swift NSObject subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28718577/3804019)

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin: Did you really read the full compiler messages? I *bet* there are messages like `note: protocol requires function bla bla bla ... note: candidate has non-matching type bla bla bla ...`

Comment: no acceptable answer sir.

Comment: `hash()` could be one problem, but there are more: For example why does `func isMediaMessage()` return a `Bool!` instead of a `Bool` as required in the protocol?

Comment: I had no idea how to read the full compiler messages. I think this only one.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin: "View -> Navigators -> Show Report navigator" or simply "Cmd-8".

Comment: BTW, also thanks to @MartinR .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. `hash` is defined as a method that returns an `NSUInteger` in the protocol. Also, `NSUInteger` can't be nil in Objective-C, so you can't return an optional. You need to change its implementation in the `Message` class to return an `UInt`

   ```
   func hash() -> UInt {
       return UInt(hash_);
   }
   ```

or simply `return hash_` and change `hash_` from `Int` to `UInt` itself.

2. `BOOL` can't be nil in Objective-C, so to conform to the protocol you need to change `isMediaMessage()` to return a non optional `Bool` by removing the `!`:

   ```
   func isMediaMessage() -> Bool {
       return isMediaMessage_;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be "hash", that is an unsigned int in the protocol and just an int in the implementation.