# JSQMessageData append Json data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to add json values in JSQMessageData to show the message on JSQMessagesViewController. The view is set up and this the lite chat(can chat only once).We use an api to `send` and `receive` messages. The problem is when I fetched data from api as `json` it returns the value. I want to append that `json` data to the rest of my `JSQMessages` objects, I tried the last few days and have failed to accomplish this. Here is the full code and `json` response.

```
    APIHandler.requestGETURL(urlString, success: { (JSON) in
        print(JSON)

        // var messageDictionary : [JSQMessageData] = []
        // this is the message object
        // i want to add the json data to my messageDictionary
        // reload collection view

        /*
         {
         "message_time" : "27-05-2017",
         "user_id" : 1924,
         "user_name" : "Tester name",
         "message" : "hi",
         "user_thumb" : "<image_path>"
         },
         {
         "message_time" : "27-05-2017",
         "user_id" : 1924,
         "user_name" : "Tester name",
         "message" : "how are you?",
         "user_thumb" : "<image_path>"
         }
         */

        // i want to 
      let arrayNames =  JSON["data"]
      self.messageDictionary.append(JSQMessageData()) 
      // I am stuck here
    }) { (Error) in
        print(Error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: You need to show your json and the declaration of JSQMessageData

Comment: Can i give the full code. I want to add those json data in JSQMessageData

Comment: Show also your JSQMessageData class ?

Comment: I didnt create data class for JSQMessageData

Comment: Are you working with jsqmessagesviewcontroller ?

Comment: yes iam using  jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Comment: You can make custom class like this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961403/swift-type-does-not-conform-to-protocol from JSQMessageData

Comment: I added but how can we append

Comment: Its working when I add static content. How can I append this json data in a for loop. I want to take the json key value "user_id", "user_name" ... on single for loop

Comment: How you are showing static data, if you want to store `user_id`, `user_name` ... WIth `JSQMessageData` then you need to create custom class that have all this properties and implement it with JSQMessageData

Comment: Thanks its working fine, did by what you said to adding Custom class for JSQMessageData

Comment: Glad you made it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're trying to parse `json` into a `JSQMessage` object. Your message data is not overly complex, it contains all the things a standard `JSQMessage` needs. So there is not any reason to create your own `JSQMessageData` object. You can just use one of the `JSQMessage` initializers. Since you are only using "Text" messages and not any other "Media" the

```
JSQMessage(senderId: <String!>, senderDisplayName: <String!>, date: <#Date>, text: <String>)
```

should be all you need. So all you need to do is get the values out of your json response. There are many ways to do this.

I am going to assume that the `json` you provided is also wrapped in a list like this

```
[
  { "message_time" : "27-05-2017",
    "user_id" : 1924,
    "user_name" : "Tester name",
    "message" : "hi",
    "user_thumb" : "<image_path>"
  },
  { "message_time" : "27-05-2017",
    "user_id" : 1924,
    "user_name" : "Tester name",
    "message" : "how are you?",
    "user_thumb" : "<image_path>"
  } 
]
```

We can utilise the `flatmap` function to get our "Messages" out of the `json` data. You also do not need a dictionary becasue there is not key for each message so just use a list that contains `JSQMessageObject`s

```
var messages:[JSQMessages] = []
var imageDictionary: [userID: String: imagePath: String] = [:]

APIHandler.requestGETURL(urlString, success: { (JSON) in
  print(JSON)
  let messagesJSON = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] ?? [[:]]
    guard let listOfMessages = JSON as? [[String: AnyObject]]
    messages: [JSQMessage] = listOfMessages.flatmap { messageData in
     guard let dateCreated = messageData["message_time"] as? Date,
       let userID = messageData["user_id"] as? String,
       let userName = messageData["user_name"] as? String,
       let text = messageData["message"] as? String  else {
          //If any of these things are missing we do not want to save the entry 
          return nil
     }

    let imagePath = messageData["user_thumb"] as? String
```

imageDictionary[userID] = imagePath
        return JSQMessage(senderId: userID, senderDisplayName: userName, date: dateCreated, text: text)

```
  }) { (let error: Error) in
     if error != nil {
        print(Error.localizedDescription)
     }
}
```

I would save your image paths into a dictionary and fetch them on a background thread that way users can view the messages while the images populate as they arrive. Then once they have loaded apply them to your messages. or you can add it to your own custom message object that conformes to the `JSQMessageDataSource` protocol. for more on how to accomplish that check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864942/argument-labels-do-not-match-any-available-overloads/38884743#38884743)

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel is saying right, your json is enough simple that you don't need to add any JSQMessageData and maybe you are actually doing some extra effort, i have faced similar kind of problem when i need to pass a NSDictionary object with JSQMessage Objects so i used a tricky way for doing that ( and it works perfectly fine :) )

not sure about your case but this helps me a lot in many situations so follow these steps :

1. convert your `json` data into string
2. now save this json string into the `accessebilityHint` property of `JSQmessage` object. like -

   `(jsqmessageObj).accessibilityHint = jsonString`
3. as according to your need as you want to use this json just extract the JSQmessage Object (like in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ! ) , just use `(jsqmessageObj).accessibilityHint` to get back your json string decode it and use it as your need.
   like - `strJson = (jsqmessageObj).accessibilityHint`

Hope this will help :p