# hash() and description() not allowed in Xcode 6.3 for NSObject

Tags: swift, reflection, overloading, nsobject

In my Swift library [EVCloudKitDao](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao) I do a lot with reflection. Because of that I have set my base class of my data objects to NSObject. Now after the upgrade to Xcode 6.3 I get an error on the 2 functions for getting the hash and the description of the object. The description function was a nice to have, but i do need the hash to make my objects working with a Set.

Here is the code that I have

```
public class EVCloudKitDataObject : NSObject, NSCoding, Printable, Hashable, Equatable {

    public func hash() -> Int {
        return self.hashValue
    }
    public func description() -> String {
        return EVReflection.description(self)
    }
}
```

The errors that I get is:

> /Users/evermeer/Desktop/dev/GitHub/EVCloudKitDao/AppMessage/AppMessage/CloudKit/EVCloudKitDataObject.swift:106:17:
>   Method 'hash()' with Objective-C selector 'hash' conflicts with getter
>   for 'hash' from superclass 'NSObject' with the same Objective-C
>   selector
>
> /Users/evermeer/Desktop/dev/GitHub/EVCloudKitDao/AppMessage/AppMessage/CloudKit/EVCloudKitDataObject.swift:86:17:
>   Method 'description()' with Objective-C selector 'description'
>   conflicts with getter for 'description' from superclass 'NSObject'
>   with the same Objective-C selector

Does anyone know how I could solve this?
You can not use override.

Comment: What do you mean by "you cannot use override"?

Comment: when you use override you get the error: Method does not override any method from its superclass

Comment: Duplicate of [Issue with conforming to Objective-C protocol from Swift NSObject subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718577/issue-with-conforming-to-objective-c-protocol-from-swift-nsobject-subclass) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the error says, in both cases there's a naming conflict between a property and a method. The most obvious way to fix is by turning your 2 methods into properties:

```
public override var hash: Int {
    return self.hashValue
}

public override var description: String {
    return EVReflection.description(self)
}
```

which can also be written as:

```
public override var hash:Int {
    get {
        return self.hashValue
    }
}
public override var description : String {
    get {
        return EVReflection.description(self)
    }
}
```

The reason why it worked in the previous version is most likely because of this:

> Swift now detects discrepancies between overloading and overriding in the Swift type system and the effective behavior seen via the Objective-C runtime.

Read more in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW3) (search for `18391046` and `18383574`)

Comment: Strange that in Xcode 6.2 it did work with these as a method. I have now changed it to properties as you said and now everything works again. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's because of a couple language fixes - read updated answer