# Swift - Method '*()' with Objective-C selector '*' conflicts with getter for '*' from superclass 'NSObject' with the same Objective-C selector

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I got this error message since update my xcode to 6.3.1.

```
/Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/Models/Message.swift:46:10: Method 'hash()' with Objective-C selector 'hash' conflicts with getter for 'hash' from superclass 'NSObject' with the same Objective-C selector
```

My code

```
var hash_ : UInt

func hash() -> UInt {
        return UInt(hash_);
    }
```

Comment: and was that tell you? that the method you are trying to define conflicts with another method of the same name! Solution: choose a different name or adapt the return type to be an exact fit for the conflicting method to override it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Issue with conforming to Objective-C protocol from Swift NSObject subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718577/issue-with-conforming-to-objective-c-protocol-from-swift-nsobject-subclass) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate: `@property(readonly) NSUInteger hash` is an Objective-C property of `NSObject`, that means there is a getter created for that variable, namely `hash()`.

You now try to define a method of the same name and the same parameters (none) but with a different return type (`UInt` instead of `NSUInteger`, which would be `Int` in swift.). Therefore you receive the given error. To resolve that issue you have two options now:

- change the return type to `Int` -> that will override the predefined hash function
- choose a different method name or add parameters

Comment: I can't, it must declared in UInt. If not, it's not satisfy the protocol.

Comment: What protocol does it not satisfy? Do you get a different error?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin That's wrong, it's Int, not Uint. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 4):

See the `NSObjectProtocol` declaration, where `hash` is declared:

```
var hash: Int { get }
```

You have three problems:

- `hash` is a `var`, not a `func`
- the type is `Int`, not `UInt`.
- you didn't use the `override` keyword

To resolve these issues, use this instead:

```
override var hash : Int {
    return /* (your hash logic) */
}
```